MAUI: WebView inside VerticalStackLayout and ScrollView does not expand (iOS)
Following simplified XAML works fine in Xamarin.Forms and Maui:
<ScrollView HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView x:Name="WebView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <WebView.Source>
                <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding html}"/>
             </WebView.Source>
        </WebView >
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>

Now in Maui because "FillAndExpand" and expand is obsolete and might not work in the future I tried setting it to "Fill", but then WebView doesn't get resized.
So I tried replacing StackLayout with VerticalStackLayout, but still doesn't expand:
<ScrollView HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <WebView x:Name="WebView" VerticalOptions="Fill">
            <WebView.Source>
                <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding html}"/>
             </WebView.Source>
        </WebView >
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>

So my question is - why does obsolete property works fine, but not the new one? And more importantly, how can I fix this issue?

You can use Grid instead of VerticalStackLayout which will expand automatically:
<ScrollView HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
    <Grid>
        <WebView x:Name="WebView">
            <WebView.Source>
                <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding html}"/>
             </WebView.Source>
        </WebView >
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>



Thank you, will try replacing with Grid.

Sounds like another lie from corporate shill, using Grid has no effect - it still does not behave as expected, on Android too.
